# ansible - encrypt ansible_become_pass

Tags: cron, ansible

I have a playbook that is run once a day via an entry in the crontab. For some of the tasks defined in the playbook I need to become root on the target machine. Thus I use `become` together with `ansible_become_pass` to gain sudo priveleges. As I run it as a cronjob I cannot use `--ask-become-pass`. On the other side I do not want to store the sudo password in plain text in my ansible hosts file. Can I somehow pass an encrypted password to ansible?

Comment: check [ansible vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html)

Comment: But does this not just shift the problem?
In the end I need to call `--ask-vault-pass` which i cannot do with cron

Comment: If you use ansible-vault as fernandezcuesta suggested, you can generate a variable and set it on your playbook or vars file encrypted. Then when you run your playbook you send an extra parameter with the vault password file path which is also encrypted, then vault will manage the hash...

Comment: The `ansible-vault` will be suited for your requirement. Please check the link **https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my best solution was to create a script (in Python) that would ask for the ansible-valut password each time it started (i would put the script in crontab `@reboot`). When I entered the password, it would be saved in a variable, thus being present in memory while the program was running in the background (to run in the background it would fork and redirect the **stdout** and **stderr**). The script would then use the Python "child" module to execute the ansible playbook (or command) and automatically send the vault password. After each ansible execution, the program would sleep for 24 hours.

I just wanted to give you an idea of a possible workaround. This is not technically a service/daemon, but it's not very different.